# Do we delete tags that duplicate a better tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, editing

When there are two tags that mean the same thing (eg high-school and secondary-education), do we delete the tag that is not preferred? Is there a way to point that out if someone then attempts to add that tag?

Discussion here has made it clear that high-school is not an international term, where secondary-education is. However, the suggestion that seems best for the overall progression (copied below) doesn't include college, which seems like a useful tag.

Copied from [a question about terms](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66/k-12-or-k-number-vs-primary-secondary-edution-vs-high-school-teachers-vs):
Perhaps the most appropriate way is to use the tags like primary-education , secondary-education , undergraduate-education and postgraduate-education . Please make the site internationally compatible. –  doraemonpaul 17 hours ago

Comment: I believe there's the ability to make tags synonyms - so that, say, secondary-education tags will automatically be retagged high-school.

Comment: As Mike suggests, this will eventually be handled using tag synonyms.  See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the high-school tag should be retagged secondary-education though. ;)

Comment: You say "college" is a useful tag, but do not give any reason for this. What specifically should be tagged "college"?  Where would "undergradtuate-ed" "postgraduate-ed" or for example "university" not work? What is missing IMO  is tertiary-education (though it might be too borad). [On the very answer  under which that comment you mention is to be found I explained this already.]

Comment: To be clear: I could imagine questions that are specific to liberal arts colleges and there might than be room for a tag in this direction. Or maybe the eduction practices in the Cambridge colleges get discussed at some point. Or maybe there is something specific to community colleges. But then *all these* colleges are not at all similar AFAIK. So the tags would be a lot more specific than the current "college" tag that seems like a catch all for (early) tertiary education questions.

Comment: @quid etc: Do we really need different tags for **exams** & **testing** & **assessment** & **grading**? Maybe one tag for all is too few, but four tags seem to me like too many!

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I tend to agree. I am not sure what exactly should be done though. See [should-assessment-and-grading-be-synonymous-tags](http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/140/) and [the-tags-around-exams-homework-and-alike-how-should-they-be-structured](http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/127/). A way to go about it could be you making a proposal in that latter thread by way of an answer, so the discussion would get anew some exposure. Of course you could also ask a new question.

Answer (score 5):

## Propose synonyms instead.

Right at the moment, there aren't enough people with the [propose synonyms](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) privilege.  In the meantime, community managers perform all moderator duties and can establish synonyms.  I've made [high-school](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-school) a synonym for [secondary-education](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secondary-education).  New questions about the topic will get the later tag rather than the former.

It's not a bad idea to suggest tag synonyms on meta so that they can be discussed by the community unless the synonym is overwhelming obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I think that on the long run these questions have to be retagged, but it will be a long and difficult process because many won't read these discussions here before asking.

These thing should be somehow formulated in the help center where we discribe the site and where we give tips to help asking good questions.

Comment: Maybe we can or should also start before the site goes public beta. As it was noticed in the comments above this should be manageable more or less automatically with the tag synonyms.