# Raising International Awareness in the Community

Tags: discussion

Understanding the various methods different countries use is one of the most interesting things about being part of an international site. I was inspired by a question that [Roland asked](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47/what-are-standard-assumptions-for-courses) about a practice in the US that I was unaware was not a standard internationally. In that discussion, one point that was repeated was that we need to be an internationally sensitive community.

- Is there a site to which we can refer users to learn more about international practices in Math Education?
- Should we develop a list of interesting differences in Math Education between countries?

Comment: Sometimes, I am afraid that differentiating by countries isn’t sufficient. Often enough I was surprised by the differences between individual schools and universities here. E.g., we had done proofs in what roughly corresponds to high school, but none of my fellow students had. (On the other hand, this is Germany, I am talking about, where it is said that it is easier to switch schools or universities from or to another country than between different German federal states.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I agree. Also, even within a given university there are often big differences (in our department, one group uses a complete different approach for their exercise groups than the rest of the department).

Answer (score 5):

I think a good start is to feed the existing Wikipedia articles. Therefore non-SE members will also benefit from our work.

- [Mathematics education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_education)
- [Mathematics education in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_education_in_the_United_States)
- Also [Category:Mathematics education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Mathematics_education) has a lot of material.

I would be glad to explain the process of [*agrégation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agr%E9gation), a French competitive exam for upcoming teachers. Within one year of preparation we tend to assess the question: [Knowing mathematics does not translate to knowing to teach mathematics. Why?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/176/knowing-mathematics-does-not-translate-to-knowing-to-teach-mathematics-why) :)